# Giro de pantalla solo en tablets

Tags: android-studio

tengo una aplicación en la que todas sus activities están forzadas a la posición 'portrait' porque el diseño no permite otra cosa en los móviles normales. Lo hago en el AndroidManifest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".Actividad"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
        tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity"
        />
```

¿Habría alguna forma de que cuando se esté usando una tablet si se pueda utilizar tanto el formato 'portrait' como el 'landscape'? Sé que tengo que crear los distintos layouts pero el problema es como permito que si es una tablet se desbloquee el giro de pantalla.
Lo olvidaba, estoy usando AndroidStudio. Agradeceré cualquier sugerencia.